# Exact sequence of groups to exact sequence sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, topological-groups, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

For a topological group $G$ and a topological space $X$, denote by $\underline{G^X}$ the sheaf of continuous functions from $X$ into $G$.

Suppose we have an exact sequence of groups
$$
1\rightarrow F\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1.
$$
What are sufficient conditions for the corresponding sequence of sheaves
$$
1\rightarrow \underline{F^X}\rightarrow \underline{G^X}\rightarrow \underline{H^X}\rightarrow 1
$$
to be exact?

Comment: Crossposted (with notice on MO, but not here): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/197904/exact-sequence-of-groups-to-exact-sequence-of-sheaves

Comment: **Please** instead of posting a new question on MO ask moderators to move the question there. That way we can avoid what happened here of having two people write the same answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactness at $\underline{F^X}$ and $\underline{G^X}$ is clear, so you are asking about surjectivity at $\underline{H^X}$. In other words, given a point $x \in X$, an open set $U \ni x$ and a continuous map $\phi : U \to H$, when can I shrink $U$ to $V \ni x$ and lift $\phi$ to $\psi: V \to G$?

I think the right condition is

> There is a nonempty open set $W$ in $H$, and a continuous section
>   $\sigma: W \to G$ of the map $G \to H$.

This implies that $\underline{G^X} \to \underline{H^X}$ is surjective. **Proof:** Let $(x, U, \phi)$ be as above. Using the group structure on $G$ and $H$, we may translate $W$ to contain $\phi(x)$ and adjust our section to still be a section. Now, take $V = \phi^{-1}(W)$. Since $\phi$ is continuous, $V$ is open, and $\sigma \circ \phi$ gives the desired lift of $\phi$. $\square$

In the other direction, if the boxed condition does not hold, then the identity map in $\underline{H^H}$ is not in the image of $\underline{G^H}$.

**EDIT** Oh, I see that Eric Wofsey has written the same thing back on MO.